# All values changes in array using vhdl

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, vhdl, fpga

I'm trying to make brick break in VHDL.
Everything went well but I have a weird problem.
In a piece of my code you see below I change the value to '0' at index (y,x) in my array when the ball reaches the edges of a brick. The problem is that all the values in my array change to 0, even when the ball is not moving (When the program start up, the ball is not moving).

```
process(Ball_x1,Ball_x2,Ball_y1,Ball_y2) begin
    x1 <= 280 + (x * 55); --edges of my brick
    x2 <= 280 + ((x + 1) * 55);
    y1 <= 108 + (y * 13);
    y2 <= 108 + ((y + 1) * 13);
    waardeArray := level1(y,x);
    if (vcnt >= y1) and (vcnt <= y2) then 
        if (Ball_x1 >= x1) and (Ball_x1 <= x2) then -- edges of my ball
            if waardeArray = '1' then
                level1(y,x) := '0';
            end if;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

The declaration of my array is

```
type levels is array ( 0 to 3, 0 to 5 ) of bit;
shared variable level1 : levels := (
                                     ('1','0','0','0','0','1'),
                                     ('0','1','0','0','1','0'),
                                     ('0','0','1','1','0','0'),
                                     ('0','0','1','1','0','0')

                                     );
```

Next variable is used to store the value of the array at place (y,x)

```
shared variable waardeArray: bit;
```

It's the intention to use Ball_x2 etc too but I just tried with 1 edge of my ball to test the code.

**Update**

```
process(Ball_x1,Ball_x2,Ball_y1,Ball_y2) begin
    x1 <= 280 + (x * 55); -- edges of my brick
    x2 <= 280 + ((x + 1) * 55);
    y1 <= 108 + (y * 13);
    y2 <= 108 + ((y + 1) * 13);
    if (vcnt >= y1) and (vcnt <= y2) then --vcnt is from another component where I send my data to my screen
        if (Ball_x1 >= x1) and (Ball_x1 <= x2) then -- left edge of my ball
            if level1(y)(x) = '1' then
                level1(y)(x) <= '1';  --I do this to test if the elements with value 1 stay 1 and the 0 stay 0 ata initialization, but every element in my array change to 1.
            else
                level1(y)(x) <= level1(y)(x);
            end if;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

Declarations

```
signal x: integer range 0 to 6 := 0;    --Six is used for something else.
signal y: integer range 0 to 3 := 0;    

signal x1: integer range 279 to 616;
signal x2: integer range 279 to 616;
signal y1: integer range 107 to 228;
signal y2: integer range 107 to 228;

signal color: std_logic_vector (7 downto 0) := "00000111";

type levels is array ( 0 to 3) of std_logic_vector (5 downto 0);
signal level1 : levels :=  ("101101",
                                     "010010",
                                     "001100",
                                     "001100");
```

This is my intention

[image]

Comment: What array is being changed; is it `waardeArray` or `level1` ?  It is hard to
dig more into this without at least the declarations, so you may consider
posting all the relevant code.  Also, only the first argument in the process
sensitivity list is used in the process, so the last three, starting with
`Ball_x2` could be removed.  You may find some useful information in the answer
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20492018/2352082 and
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20526229/2352082.

Comment: With a shared variable it may be updated in another process, so maybe you must look elsewhere for where the change is made.

Comment: In other processes I only use the value of my array, I don't change anything. Only in this process.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use shared variables.  If you need to communicate a value between processes, use a signal.  You can't be sure of the order at which updates compared to reads occur using shared variables.  Well, you can, but you have to use protected types.

Also, in your process, you are looking at the values of `x`, `y` and `vcnt`.  But those signals (I hope they are signals not shared variables :) are not in the sensitivity list of the process, so when they change, your process will not be triggered.

Comment: I changed all my shared variables to signals, but even then all my elements in my array change to 1.
The process should only start when the ball is moving, not when I change the index of my array.
I changed my array also to a 1D array with STD_LOGIC_VECTOR elements and change the values of the STD_LOGIC_VECTOR but even then i've the same problem..

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code as it is now.  And your testbench, and some simulation waveforms showing when the lements change to '1' relative to other signals of interest?

Comment: I did not made any testbenches so far. I'm not so good with VHDL, however, I should make some soon.

Comment: How are you seeing that your signals are changing to all '1's without a testbench?

Comment: If the element is one it should show a brick on my screen, else if the element is zero there should be a empty place (no brick).

Comment: Ahh, you're doing it all in an FPGA?  I highly recommend getting some sort of testbench going, although it's a bit of a pain upfront, it's vastly quicker than the old "write code, synthesise, place and route, test" cycle! And an excellent skillset to have :)

Comment: Ok, i'll try to find the problem using testbenches. Thanks!